# Load Action Script Photoshop CS4

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions, cs4

Sorry for my English.

I'd like to load an action to photoshop cs4 with JavaScript but nowhere can I find this function.

This function doesn't work:

`app.loadAction( new File( 'E:/Folder/Actions/My-template-action.atn' ) );`.

When I use this function, Photoshop displays the following error:

`Error 24: app.loadAction is not a function.`

Please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know how to do that is to use `File.execute()` command, however for this to work `.atn` files should be among the known file types (so the default option to open it would be a Photoshop), but in my experience, in 99% of the cases it works.

P.S. I think `app.loadAction` is for Illustrator only.

Comment: Works this `File( 'E:/Folder/Actions/My-template-action.atn' ).execute();`
Thanks